# Unresolved Error in Django Signal

Tags: python, django

I want to populate `artist`field of `Album` model with `pre_save` function while saving an instance `Musician` model.

***models.py***

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name



class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    num_stars = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.artist

@receiver(pre_save,sender = Musician)
def create_album(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    sm = Album()
    sm.artist = instance
    sm.save()
```

But when I am trying to create an instance of Musician Model from admin, it shows this error upon hitting save button.

```
Exception Type: ValueError at /admin/sig/musician/add/
Exception Value: save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'artist'.
```

I cant understand how to solve this  `sm.save()`  error! Please be helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pre_save` signal is calling **before** `Musician` instance saved to db. But you cannot set as artist value unsaved instance. You should change signal to `post_save`. In this case Musician will be saved at the moment album is creating:

```
@receiver(post_save,sender = Musician)
def create_album(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    sm = Album()
    sm.artist = instance
    sm.save()
```

Comment: well, thnaks for answer. @neverwalkalone so when to use  `pre_save` ! is there any conditions ?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak pre_save using in cases when you need to perform some actions before object will be saved. For instance to add slug.